# Compatibility issues with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am facing a problem with this site www.airmaster.dk. In IE 8 the java script is not rendering correctly as it suppose to and I cant figure out why it is happening.

It's rendering the elements something like this:

```
<DIV class=nav-bar jQuery1830605484465614684="10"><A class=opener-subnav href="javascript:void(0);" jQuery1830605484465614684="8">Genveje</A>
```

as it suppose to render it like this :

```
<div class="nav-bar">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="opener-subnav">Genveje</a>
```

chrome, firefox, IE9 and above
[image: chrome, firefox, IE9 and above]

IE 8 and below
[image: IE 8 and below]

IE 8 double header and footer close tags
[image]

Jquery 
http://www.speedyshare.com/pHwuX/jquery.main-1.js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: both elements are the same... what is te problem you are facing

Comment: duplicate question.. Same user is asking Questions again and again.. :(

Comment: with due respect i have been through all these links and posted the question again. Now i know why these attributes are there but dont know how to get rid of them?

Comment: so how really does it matter.I mean if div is rendered as DIV it doesn't seem to affect the actual html rendering.

Comment: @UmarKhan If you want to get rid of them you have to remove jquery! If you had read all those links then you should have realized that!

Comment: @UmarKhan Okay, now we are getting somewhere. These screenshoots really help. However to fully understand what is going on, could you create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ that reproduces the problem or a link to your page?. Also I think you have some **misunderstandings** here: Javascript isn't something that gets rendered. It only produces renderable html code. Therefor your problem is not the jquery tags, but your **HTML/CSS** code instead that is incompatible with IE8.

Comment: these menu bars are styled with jquery could that be a problem as well?

Comment: Depends on which jQuery version you have and on the code you are using

Comment: @UmarKhan As I already said: This has absolutly nothing to do with javascript. This issue lies within your html generation. You should show us the code that generates the html code!

Comment: @RononDex i also added the link to my javascript file which is handling the styling i hope i would be helpful

Comment: @UmarKhan Could you please setup a fiddle here that reproduces your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/. It is hard to understand why or what your code is doing without the HTML / CSS

Comment: It would be impossible todo so in jsfiddle as this web site is built on CMS

Comment: @UmarKhan Just copy your HTML when viewing the source code in a browser, then take your CSS and Javascript and put it in a jsfiddle ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because HTML5 tages like `header` and `footer` does not support on IE8 or below.

You should use 3rdparty library such as **[html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)** to render HTML5 tags correctly.

Comment: It was exactly this problem. now its working 100% fine as it should be :). thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

IE just show you DOM node properties added by javascript. `jQuery1830605484465614684` is just the jQuery UID for inner usage.

**ADD:**

Your stylesheets not applied. May be its have syntax error or to many selectors.

Comment: yes you are rite but then why its a problem in IE8 and how to get rid of it

Comment: I mean how this problem can be  fixed?

Comment: @UmarKhan Why is it even a problem?

Comment: it runs fine in all browsers except internet explorer 8 and below. In internet Explorer it literally messup the whole website. if needed i can post a screen short

Comment: @UmarKhan Yes that would definetly help us, as these tags added by jquery should not affect the rendering, you must have another problem with your code

Comment: @RononDex I have update my post with screen-shots